# Return Result Set That Populates Class With Multiple Collections In Dapper

Tags: c#, dapper

I am looking to return a result set that populates a class with multiple collections in Dapper (if possible). There are plenty of good examples with a single collection and a splitOn, but I would like to see if it is possible to populate more than one collection.

3 simplified classes:

```
class QCLogData
{
   public int QCLogId { get; set; }
   public string Stage { get; set; }
   public bool PassQCTesting { get; set; }
 
   public ICollection<QCLogPerson> Testers { get; set; }
   public ICollection<QCInstrument> Instruments { get; set; }
}

class QCLogPerson
{
      public int PersonId { get; set; }
}

class QCInstrument
{
  public string InstrumentNumb { get; set; }
}

QCLogId Stage   PassQCTesting   TesterUserId    InstrumentNumb
------- -----   -------------   ------------    --------------
1920    1       0               null            null

1925    4       1               2               null

1926    2       0               null            77

1927    6       0               4               null
1927    6       0               5               null

1931    1       1               2               88
1931    1       1               2               94
1931    1       1               6               88
1931    1       1               6               94

2206    5       0               20              80
2206    5       0               20              88
2206    5       0               20              93
2206    5       0               25              80
2206    5       0               25              88
2206    5       0               25              93
```

Data filled:

```
QCLogId: 1920,  Stage: 1, PassQCTesting: 0
Testers [] ; Instruments []

QCLogId: 1925,  Stage: 4, PassQCTesting: 1
Testers [2] ; Instruments []

QCLogId: 1926,  Stage: 2, PassQCTesting: 0
Testers [] ; Instruments [77]

QCLogId: 1927,  Stage: 6, PassQCTesting: 0
Testers [4, 5] ; Instruments []

QCLogId: 1931,  Stage: 1, PassQCTesting: 1
Testers [2, 6] ; Instruments [88, 94]

QCLogId: 2206,  Stage: 5, PassQCTesting: 0
Testers [20, 25] ; Instruments [80, 88, 93]
```

Tried in Dapper, clearly not the correct approach for multiple collections.

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var sql = @"select QCL.QCLogId, Stage, PassQCTesting, TesterUserId as PersonId, InstrumentNumb
                from dbo.QCLog QCL
                left join dbo.QCLogTester QCT on QCL.QCLogId = QCT.QCLogId
                left join dbo.QCLogInstrument QCINSTR on QCL.QCLogId = QCINSTR.QCLogId;";

    var LogItemWithTesters = con.Query<QCLogData, QCLogPerson, QCInstrument, QCLogData>(sql, (qcData, qcTester, qcInstrument) =>
    {
        var tester = new QCLogPerson { PersonId = qcTester.PersonId };
        qcData.Testers.Add(tester);

        var instrument = new QCInstrument { InstrumentNumb = qcInstrument.InstrumentNumb };
        qcData.Instruments.Add(instrument);

        return qcData;
    }, splitOn: "PersonId, InstrumentNumb");

    var result = LogItemWithTesters.GroupBy(p => p.QCLogId).Select(g =>
    {
        var groupedQCLog = g.First();
        groupedQCLog.Testers = g.Select(p => p.Testers.Single()).ToList();
        return groupedQCLog;
    });

    return result.ToList();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend doing multiple queries and joining the data together in C# afterward. I have found that Dapper multi-mapping pushes a lot of object building logic outside of where the type system or unit tests can assist you, even though it does save some typing.

Comment: Agreed, I find `QueryMultiple` much better than `splitOn` for most of these kinds of queries. Put the first resultset in a dictionary, then map the second resultset into it

Comment: I appreciate your responses. I'll go with the multiple queries and the dictionary.

Comment: As a side point, the result from `Query` or `QueryMultiple` should be in a `using` (note that a `foreach` also implements `using`)